# Cant connect ot remote MySQL DataBase from JavaFX application

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have created an application, that communicates with a remote MySQL database, which is on my laptop. The app work fine, when I use my localhost to connect like this:

```
public class DbConncetion {
   public Connection Connect(){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cms?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false","root","");
            return con;
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);       
        }
        return null;
       }

}
```

It works just great. But when I use my public IP addres instead of "localhost", the app throws:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I look a lot in this forum, but I didn't find anything. I create user and give him all privileges in my XAMPP MySQL like that:

[This is pic from there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZGep.png)

I configure the router, but i'm not sure is it correct:
[This is pic from there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvF5b.png)
Can anyone told me, where i go wrong ? 
Thanks in advance :)

And this is the full stacktrace:
t

```
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2088)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at DBconnection.DbConncetion.Connect(DbConncetion.java:24)
    at javafxapplication1.Main1Controller.loadData(Main1Controller.java:208)
    at javafxapplication1.Main1Controller.lambda$new$0(Main1Controller.java:232)
    at com.sun.scenario.animation.shared.TimelineClipCore.visitKeyFrame(TimelineClipCore.java:239)
    at com.sun.scenario.animation.shared.TimelineClipCore.playTo(TimelineClipCore.java:180)
    at javafx.animation.Timeline.impl_playTo(Timeline.java:176)
    at javafx.animation.AnimationAccessorImpl.playTo(AnimationAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at com.sun.scenario.animation.shared.InfiniteClipEnvelope.timePulse(InfiniteClipEnvelope.java:110)
    at javafx.animation.Animation.impl_timePulse(Animation.java:1102)
    at javafx.animation.Animation$1.lambda$timePulse$25(Animation.java:186)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.animation.Animation$1.timePulse(Animation.java:185)
    at com.sun.scenario.animation.AbstractMasterTimer.timePulseImpl(AbstractMasterTimer.java:344)
    at com.sun.scenario.animation.AbstractMasterTimer$MainLoop.run(AbstractMasterTimer.java:267)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:506)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:490)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$404(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:341)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2251)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2104)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:211)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
    ... 35 more

Feb 18, 2017 2:23:03 PM DBconnection.DbConncetion Connect
SEVERE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2163)
```

Comment: ping your database, check if your firewall is not block you

Comment: How exactly ?  Which address to ping ?

Comment: the ip that make this problem the public IP

Comment: Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 6ms, Average = 3ms

Comment: did you check if the port 3306 is open in that ip address ? you can use this piece of code http://stackoverflow.com/a/40571839/5558072

Comment: Return this: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
false

Comment: then your connection to this ip and this port is not allow, you should to check your firewall, try to stop it for a moment and check again

Comment: what still the same? the socket check?

Comment: IIRC the default install of MySQL only listens on 127.0.0.1. Also please post the full stacktrace, the "NullPointerException" shown in your error is rather suspect.

Comment: YCF_L  Yes, still return false

Comment: I upload the full stacktrace..

Comment: You might be in need of "port forwarding" your internet router.
I am pretty much sure that if you type your public ip address in your mobile browser, then also it will refuse to connect your phone to your localhost pc server

Comment: i do it, but still the same..

Comment: What happens when you type public ip along with the port (example. 200.111.21.09:8080) in your mobile phone's browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must allow the application ip address in Mysql user configuration, in your pic you have masked the ip allowed, that ip must be the application server ip.

If you run your web application from the same local network of the DB Host you cannot connect to the public IP of your DB Host, the router cannot simply do that.

So for your local test you must use localhost.

When you will deploy the app you must use the public.

By the way, it is not a good practice to expose mysql db port to internet.